# CSS3 Transitions and borders

Tags: css, css-transitions

I'm trying to reverse engineer the menu on this web page (this is just a personal project, not trying to steal their work).

http://clapat.ro/themes/eleven/color/

However, I can't seem to get the transition effect to work. When I add the border-top on, it's pushing the content of the  down instead of staying nicely in-line like in the example.

Also, the border seems to "blind" upwards, but when I do it, it blinds downwards.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: can you put some HTML/CSS on what you have so far? or a fiddle example of what you have so far?

Comment: Yes of course! Silly me. Link is in the description.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is causing the problem:

```
.nav > li > a {
    display: block;
}
```

which is coming from bootstrap.css If you remove that bit of CSS it works correctly.

You can override that style in index2.php by adding `display: inline;`:

```
.navbar a, .navbar a:active, .navbar a:visited {
    color: #7f7f7f;
    padding-top: 35px;
    height: 90px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 14px;
    padding-bottom: 45px;
    display: inline;         /* added this line */
}
```